# How do you handle user communication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site where users need to get in touch with us, sometimes to request a demo of the product.

What is the best (and cheapest) way to handle things like a demo request or basic non-social feedback?

Options I can think of:

1. Create a database table for demo requests then check it periodically (or e-mail to myself from it, whatever).
2. Send a one-off e-mail to my inbox when a request comes in (seems very weak).
3. Hire some company (equivalent of UserVoice or GetSatisfaction) that can handle such communications.

What do you suggest? What do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on how you prefer to handle things. What is easier for you to check? Your inbox, a page with requests from users? Either one is fairly straight forward to build in rails. I would suggest not going with #3 unless you absolutely have to due to workload. Being in touch with the customers will give you a better idea of what's going on with your product.

What i built before was a simple ticketing system. You can build it with the scaffold generator, add name:string description:text status:integer as fields. Define the statuses as a hash in the model, update the forms, and block all actions aside from new and create to admin only users. That way regular users or guests can submit a new request.

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.